# Lodash: how to create a array with new object structure

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

Let's say I have an array:

```
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];
```

I want to create a new array:

```
var users = [
  {person: {item : { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true }}},
  {person: {item : { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false }}},
  {person: {item : { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}}}
];
```

Obviously, workaround is using for loop to create new array, but I'm using lodash for manipulating my arrays in my project.

Just wonder is there any lodash solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a new structure.

```js
var users = [{ user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true }, { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false }, { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}],
    result = users.map(item => ({ person: { item } }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think the previous, multi-line format was more readable :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this via [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) since it `2nd` parameter is an actual [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
var users = [ { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true }, { user: 'fred', age: 40, active: false }, { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true} ];

const result = Array.from(users, i => ({ person: {item: i} }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Using `Array.from()` with a map function here as opposed to just `Array.prototype.map()` doesn't really make sense unless what you're trying to convert actually isn't an `Array` (e.g. a `NodeList` or something which doesn't have the .map() method).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will create a new array and since you can use arrow function in a single line you can avoid return and using es6 destructuring you can achieve in the below way.

I hope it will solve your issue

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

var newUsers = users.map(o => ({person: {item: o}}))

console.log("new array with inside person and inside item property", newUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lodash, then you can use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map)

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

var convertedUsers = _.map(users, user => ({person: {item : {user}}}));

console.log(convertedUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this will mean that this re-uses the the original objects, so changes to those will be carried over to the mapped output:

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

var convertedUsers = _.map(users, user => ({person: {item : user}}));

users[0].user = 'betty'; //change barney -> betty

//change is reflected in the already mapped output
console.log(convertedUsers[0].person.item.user);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If this is undesirable, then you can create new objects with the same content:

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

var convertedUsers = _.map(users, user => ({person: {item : {...user}}})); //note the {...users}

users[0].user = 'betty'; //change the original barney -> betty

//no change in the mapped result
console.log(convertedUsers[0].person.item.user);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do the exact same thing with plain JavaScript and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

var convertedUsersReusingObjects = users.map(user => ({person: {item : user}}));

var convertedUsersWithNewObjects = users.map(user => ({person: {item : {...user}}})) ;

console.log("convertedUsersReusingObjects:",  convertedUsersReusingObjects);

console.log("----------------");


console.log("convertedUsersWithNewObjects:",  convertedUsersWithNewObjects);

console.log("----------------");

users[0].user = 'betty'; //change the original barney -> betty

console.log("reusing objects: ", convertedUsersReusingObjects[0].person.item.user);
console.log("new objects: ",  convertedUsersWithNewObjects[0].person.item.user);
```